# is there any function like "strptime" in java

Tags: java

suppose there is a time_string like: `"wallclock(2011-09-22T01:52:00)"`

in C language, I can use `"strptime(time_string, "wallclock(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)", &tm)`"

to get date time and store it into the struct tm,

and then use `mktime(&tm)` to get the date in seconds

But in Java, I find no way about how to transfer string `"wallclock(2011-09-22T01:52:00)"`,

is there any way to do this job?  thank you :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("'wallclock('yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss')'");
Date parsed = format.parse(text);
```

(Note that you probably want to set the time zone of `format` appropriately.)

Or preferrably (IMO) use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to do the parsing:

```
String pattern = "'wallclock('yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss')'";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.forPattern(pattern);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(text);
```

This will parse to a `LocalDateTime` which doesn't *have* a time zone.

In Java 8, you'd use [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead.

Comment: I just wanted to add to this answer (because it is the one people will look at) that Joda Time has been integrated into Java 8, and the [DateTimeFormatter is documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: @drakej: Well, a lot of the ideas in java.time are similar to those in Java 8, but I wouldn't say that it's been "integrated" as such. I've updated the answer to include a link though.

Comment: That is fair, I would restrict my statement to saying the original author of Joda led the new api design.

Answer (score 1):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

use `SimpleDateFormat` class. It provides the functionality you need.